# Regex. Continue matching

Tags: c#, .net, regex

need help on Regex. Say I have the following text:

```
* 1 FETCH (UID 1 FLAGS (\\Flag1 \\Flag2 \\Flag3 ....)
```

Is it possible to extract all of the flags? So a match (.NET) that will contain the groups Flag1, Flag2, Flag3.

I can use

```
FLAGS \((?<flags>.*?\)
```

to get `\\Flag1 \\Flag2 \\Flag3 ....`, which is close, but not quite there.

Comment: Sorry cannot seem to edit my post. The regex that i was using is  FLAGS \((?<flags>.*?)\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (tested online):

```
((?<flags>\\\\.*?)\s)
```

Update: this should get rid of the bracket in the end:

```
(?<flags>\\\\.*?)(\s|\))
```

Comment: This seems to only get "Flag1". Is it possible to tell the regex engine to continue searching?

Comment: It should give several groups (but I see extra bracket on the end...)

Comment: @Umair, Use the `Captures` property of the match Group to iterate all substrings matched by the group.

Comment: Thanks alxx, I am using a slightly modified version of yours: (\\\\(?<flags>.*?))(\s|\)). Seems to give me what I want. However, how can I tell that regex engine that there is a FLAGS string before it? (In case there are other similar matches after but are NOT a part FLAGS).

Comment: If all your flags are like Flag1, Flag2 and so on, you can use "Flag\d+" instead on ".*?".

Comment: You can limit valid symbols for flags with [A-Za-z0-9]. Give an example of your data, and we'll find something.